# How to Prevent Sharing Sqlite In-memory Store Among Multiple Test Methods

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

Technologies: .Net Core, Sqlite Inmemory, C#, Xunit

I'm trying to use Sqlite Inmemory Provider for mocking the database with Xunit. I want to have a fresh store (Set of text data) with each test execution. However Store seems to be sharing between multiple test methods, Hence I'm getting anomalies with test results.

Here is my code. I'm creating a new Sqlite connection with each test execution and disposing it at the end. There is no deference whether test execution is equential and parallel.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
[InlineData(3)]
public async Task WhenPassingValidId_ReturnRecord(int id)
{
  using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:"))
  {
       connection.Open();

       var options = DbHelper.GetSqliteContextOptions(connection);

       using (IDataContext context = new DataContext(options))
       {
           await SetupTestDataAsync(context);
       }

       using (IDataContext context = new DataContext(options))
       {
           var service = new LookupService(context);

           var lookup = await service.GetAsync(id);

           Assert.NotNull(lookup);
        }
   }              
}

private async static Task SetupTestDataAsync(IDataContext context)
{
        context.LookupHeaders.AddRange(GetLookupHeaders());
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        context.Lookups.AddRange(GetLookups());
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public static DbContextOptions<DataContext> GetSqliteContextOptions(SqliteConnection connection)
{
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
               .UseSqlite(connection)
               .Options;

        using (var context = new DataContext(options, CreateRequestContext()))
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();           
        }

        return options;
}
```

Is there a way to scope Sqlite In-memory database for a single test method?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the symptoms of _Store seems to be sharing between multiple test methods_? And what is the `Store`?

Comment: The database should only exist while the connection is open [try closing the connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite)

Comment: Fabio: I have added a unique constraint (Composite) on Lookup Entity. One of the symptom is,  when seeding test data it complains about unique constraint violation. Which means someone else has inserted data while another one trying to insert. But when running the failed tests isolately, they execute successfully. 

Lloyd: Connection is auto closing when disposing at the end of the using block right?

Comment: That's the normal interpretation of the using statement which is correct in almost all cases. However their own example has a try finally block specifically for the connection with using statements inside that block so I suspect in memory may be another exception to the rule.